# Underline warnings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to get all warnings underlined in the source code, similar to how errors are underlined?

When I write `#warning This is a warning` it gets a green squiggly underline, but for code analysis warnings, stylecop warnings and stylecop+ warnings, there's no underline.

Comment: No, these are separate tools that are not integrated with the IDE editor.  Just keep the Error List window handy, double click a line in that window to move the editor to the code that produced the warning.

Comment: @HansPassant It would have been nice forcing the warnings to appear in the code so that all team members see them.

Comment: These are free tools, no reason your team members couldn't run them as well.  Which is always better than "you screwed up here dummy!" comments.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, they do, they are integrated into the build process and ran for every build they do. However all compiler warnings are ignored. :/

Comment: if nobody wants to deal with these warnings then just turn the tools off, problem solved.  At least you won't get them in the habit of ignoring real compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an extension for it, Underliner.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5eb0ad7c-839d-4db4-9ab7-84b140f35c73

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tool like `ReSharper` to see these warnings.

[ReSharper Site](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: Does it pick up all warnings regardless of it's source?

Comment: yes almost all the warning even you can add customize warnings.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the feature described? I don't want to use another analysis engine, but have the warnings from all compilation steps underlined.

Comment: you can explore their site.

Comment: I did. I only found info about their analysis engine, and how I can import stylecop rules. I understand that it will underline what their engine finds, but it doesn't afaik pick up the warnings from compilation. I would love to be wrong.